# How to rewrite this into the Leibniz notation?

Tags: integration

We are studying integrals at school and my books uses a quite nice method, but the notation is bothering me, this is an example:

*Find the primitive function of $f(x) = 3x^2(x^3 + 2)^4$*.

Notice that $[x^3 + 2]' = u' = 3x^2$. So we rewrite this to $f(x) = d(x^2+2)(x^3+2)^4 = u^4du = d\dfrac{1}{5}u^5 = d\dfrac{1}{5}(x^3+2)^5$.

$F(x) = \dfrac{1}{5}(x^3+2)^5 + c$.

I understand all of this, except for the notation. Of course it wouldn't take anybody a long time to just remember this notation, however it just bothers me that I don't understand it. This is the part where I get confused:

$$u^4du = d\dfrac{1}{5}u^5$$

Shouldn't this just be $u^4du = \dfrac{1}{5}u^5$? Why does the $d$ remain? Also in the next step I don't understand what the purpose of the $d$ is (no pun intended), it seems to me just using $u^4du = \dfrac{1}{5}u^5$ is better.

Also, is it not a problem to leave out the $\int$?

I would rewrite the answer like this:

$f(x) = d(x^2+2)(x^3+2)^4 = \int u^4du = \dfrac{1}{5}u^5 = \dfrac{1}{5}(x^3+2)^5$.

$F(x) = \dfrac{1}{5}(x^3+2)^5 + c$.

Is this valid too? If not, what would the 'cleanest' way be?

p.s. - My objection with my own method is that it seems as if the $\int$ suddenly appears out of nowhere, but then again it's just the Leibniz' notation so that doesn't strike me as a dealbreaker.

Answer (score 1):

The equation $f(x) = d(x^2+2)(x^3+2)^4$ is not quite correct.  A function cannot be equal to a differential.  To justify the formula one could either replace the "d" by $\frac{d}{dx}$, or replace $f$ by $dF$.

On the other hand, the formula $u^4du = d\dfrac{1}{5}u^5$ is correct.  To give it a form more familiar to a modern reader, write $u^4\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{d\dfrac{1}{5}u^5}{dx}$

Answer (score 0):

$d(\frac{u^5}{5})=d(\frac{u^5}{5})\frac{du}{du}=\frac{d(\frac{u^5}{5})}{du}du$. Leibniz notation is wonderful because it makes using the chain rule as easy to remember to do as using division.